# Insert text in image in HTML page

Tags: html

I have to insert some text in the image shown below. The text is ready but I do not know where to get the image from. Also, I am not sure how I would insert/place the text on the image. Does anyone know where I might get such images and how to insert text into it? I looked around on the Net but did not find much help. I hope my question is not too vague. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Use `background-image` in CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possibilities for that.

1. Using PHP to process image. (your homework for [GD functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php))
2. Using CSS and HTML to place text over image.
3. Using CSS and HTML to have background image for text.

**2.**

```css
.background {
  background: url('http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/paper-note-background4.jpg') no-repeat top left transparent;
  position: relative;
  width: 570px;
  height: 264px;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <span class="text">Give me burger</span>
</div>
```

**3.**

```css
.background {
  background: url('http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/paper-note-background4.jpg') no-repeat top left transparent;
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 284px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">Give me burger</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried number 3. It worked!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

you need to place your text in another div and make this div overlap the div that holds the image.

```
<a href="http://css-tricks.com/3118-text-blocks-over-image/" target="_blank">Inspiré de CSS-Tricks</a>
<div class="fiddle">
    <div class="content">
        <h4>CSS LavaLamp nav</h4>
        <p class="date">Novembre 2011</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aNUjB/14/

Comment: Your JSFiddle contains lots of unnecessary code for such simple example...